How to configure Quarkus for JMS with RabbitMQ
I want to implement JMS request-reply model so that user synchronous request can be served in a non-blocking fashion to serve a large number of request.
Want to go with RabbitMQ. Quarkus documentation for JMS setup is based on ActiveMQ. How can I setup Quarkus JMS with RabbitMQ?
Any link or sample would help.

How can you have a request that is both synchronous and non-blocking? Those seem to contradict each other.

@agarwal_achhnera It's hard to tell because the requirements you mentioned are a bit general.
Just for your information, RabbitMQ is not a JMS provider. If performance is a concern, you should think twice before using synchronous communication, (unless it's going to be used in a non blocking way.).

From user perspective it will be synchronous, but internal processing should be non-blocking. like tomcat server in quarkus can server only 200 request and will start queue further request. if getting 10K request at once and first 200 are stuck that remaining will also get stuck. So don't want that nature. at server processing should be non-blocking after submitting request to req-queue for jms

I think your best option is to use the low level vertx-rabbitmq-client.
This supports synchronous messaging in a non blocking way.
